# TestCafe headless mode - Safari

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm evaluating TestCafe as a potential UI testing tool for our team. The target browser is Safari. Is that correct that headless tests cannot be run with Safari?

Answer (score 3):

There is not a headless mode for Safari. It isn't unique to TestCafe; you won't be able to run in headless mode in Safari with any testing framework.

Source: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251837694